# How to fetch Twitter twits in swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I have integrated twitter sdk for login and wants to fetch tweets is there any api by twitter so that I can fetch users tweets data

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at this page in Twitter's developer documentation? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/overview

The documentation states:

> **GET statuses/show/:id**
>
> Returns a single Tweet, specified by the id parameter. The Tweet’s
>   author will also be embedded within the Tweet.

Additionally, to get tweets in bulk (up to 100), you can use:

> **GET statuses/lookup**
>
> Returns fully-hydrated Tweet objects for up to 100 Tweets per request, as specified by comma-separated values passed
>   to the id parameter.

If that page specifically doesn't solve your issue, then have a look at some of the others in that same section.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20777033)

Comment: @DavidWalschots I've added relevant quotes from the link I'd initially referenced